# How to merge a file to a precompiled exe application

Tags: c#

I have designed and created two seperate windows application ( say winapp1 and winapp2). Winapp1 creates a file(say file.txt) in the disk containing some text. And I need to merge this file.txt with precompiled version of winapp2 ie winapp2.exe so that the winapp2 can display it.

Winapp1 creates a file with different contents each execution time. And for each file there will be a copy of winapp2 that needs to be merged.

Is there a way to this? If there is, help me.
And my English is not so good. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Why do they have to be two different applications? They could easily be one application with two different windows. What's your motivation?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, (assuming that releasing the source code for winapp2 to the system that runs winapp1 doesn't present problems) is to have the entire source for the winapp2 project accessible to winapp1.  The source should include a blank copy of the file as an embedded resource.  Winapp1 can then modify the source file and use MSBuild to build a fresh copy of Winapp2.

To modify the text file, you should be able to just use the normal file manipulation .NET methods and to call MSBuild, you may be able to do it via a .NET class, but you can certainly just call the msbuild executable from the relevant .NET framework folder in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ and pass in the full path of the project file.